# Error: Input("No benchmarks found which match your input.")

Tags: benchmark

```
$ cargo build --release --features runtime-benchmarks
$ ./target/release/dorafactory-node benchmark --chain dev --execution=wasm --wasm-execution=compiled --pallet pallet_template --extrinsic do_something -
-steps 20 --repeat 50 --json-file=raw.json --output ./

=====report=====

2022-03-27 03:38:52 assembling new collators for new session 0 at #0    
2022-03-27 03:38:52 assembling new collators for new session 1 at #0    
Error: Input("No benchmarks found which match your input.")
```

Comment: which branch are you compiling of https://github.com/DoraFactory/dorafactory-node ?

Comment: this is on `add-fees`. thanks! https://github.com/doraFactory/dorafactory-node/blob/add-fees/pallets/quadratic-funding/src/benchmarking.rs

Comment: What is the output of: `./target/release/dorafactory-node benchmark --chain=dev --list`? This should list all of your available benchmarks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like this line is missing:

```rust
list_benchmark!(list, extra, pallet_dao_core, DaoCoreModule);
```

(or whatever pallet your do_something extrinsic is in)

(`./target/release/dorafactory-node benchmark --chain=dev --list` did not seem to show the benchmark)

Comment: oh, I lost `list_benhmark`, thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Using `--dev` instead of `--chain dev` is a better option for these kinds of tests. The reason is `--dev` has an implicit `--tmp` which makes sure you don’t need to deal with the previous history of your development tests. It starts a fresh chain for you. In your case I’m afraid that while you’re running a new client with the benchmark features built-in, your runtime is still coming from your previous builds, meaning it doesn’t feature the benchmark option. This is because the runtime would only change on a runtime upgrade. But when you start a fresh dev blockchain the currently built runtime will be used as your runtime.

Comment: emmm, It's same. still failed.

Comment: Can you instead of pallet_template and doSomthing pass “*” and check if it runs?